# Shift every cell in a row to the left following a cell that's been unmerged

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that copies a column of values from a weekly updated inventory sheet called "Counts" and pastes and transposes them into the next empty row on another sheet "Plates per Week" for record keeping.

```
'selects and copies ranges containg total plate counts'
Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range, multipleRange As Range
Set range1 = Sheets("Counts").Range("F3:F32")
Set range2 = Sheets("Counts").Range("F35:F39")
Set range3 = Sheets("Counts").Range("F42:F46")
Set multipleRange = Union(range1, range2, range3)

'copies entire range of counts'
multipleRange.Copy

'transposes and pastes counts into next blank row on plates per week sheet'
Sheets("Plates per Week").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

The range from "Counts" includes some vertically merged cells (they're the devil, I know). Right now I have a line of code that unmerges every cell in "Plates per Week"

```
'unmerges cells all cells in sheet'
Sheets("Plates per Week").Cells.UnMerge
```

This obviously screws with the headers the values should fall under on the table I'm creating on "Plates per Week".

My current running idea is after each cell that has been unmerged, shift each cell following that to the left by 1. I know that the merged cells from "Counts" will always be cells `F6:F28`, which will always end up in `E3:AB3` on "Plates per Week". Not sure how to go about coding this bit, would appreciate any ideas as I'm not great with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off with a slightly different approach not using copy/paste:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, arr, i As Long
    
    Set rng = Sheets("Counts").Range("F3:F32,F35:F39,F42:F46") 'source range
    ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To rng.Cells.Count) 'resize to max. possible size
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells 'loop over the cells in the source range
        'is this cell either unmerged or the first cell in a merged area?
        If c.Address = c.MergeArea.Cells(1).Address Then
            i = i + 1
            arr(1, i) = c.Value 'add the cell value
        End If
    Next c
    
    'put the values on the sheet
    Sheets("Plates per Week").Range("B" & Rows.Count). _
         End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, i).Value = arr

End Sub
```